# Why does this fail in LyX 2.1.3 but works in .Rnw?

Tags: lyx, r, knitr, rnw

This code works fine in `.Rnw` but does not work  in `LyX 2.1.3`. In LyX 2.1.3 it throws the following error:

```
Error in getModel.baseGmm(all_args, ...): could not find function "is"
```

Any idea how to solve this problem. Thanks in advance for your help.

```
%% LyX 2.1.2 created this file.  For more info, see http://www.lyx.org/.
%% Do not edit unless you really know what you are doing.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[sc]{mathpazo}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{verbose,tmargin=2.5cm,bmargin=2.5cm,lmargin=2.5cm,rmargin=2.5cm}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{2}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[unicode=true,pdfusetitle,
 bookmarks=true,bookmarksnumbered=true,bookmarksopen=true,bookmarksopenlevel=2,
 breaklinks=false,pdfborder={0 0 1},backref=false,colorlinks=false]
 {hyperref}
\hypersetup{
 pdfstartview={XYZ null null 1}}
\begin{document}
<<setup, include=FALSE, cache=FALSE>>=
library(knitr)
# set global chunk options
opts_chunk$set(fig.path='figure/minimal-', fig.align='center', fig.show='hold')
options(formatR.arrow=TRUE,width=90)
@


\title{A Minimal Demo of knitr}


\author{Yihui Xie}

\maketitle
You can test if \textbf{knitr} works with this minimal demo. OK, let's
get started with some boring random numbers:

<<boring-random>>=
library(gmm)

# Random numbers of a normal distribution
# First we generate normally distributed random numbers and compute the two parameters:
n <- 1000
x <- rnorm(n, mean = 4, sd = 2)
# Implementing the 3 moment conditions
g <- function(tet, x)
{
  m1 <- (tet[1] - x)
  m2 <- (tet[2]^2 - (x - tet[1])^2)
  m3 <- x^3 - tet[1]*(tet[1]^2 + 3*tet[2]^2)
  f <- cbind(m1, m2, m3)
  return(f)
}
# Implementing the jacobian
Dg <- function(tet, x)
{
  jacobian <- matrix(c( 1, 2*(-tet[1]+mean(x)), -3*tet[1]^2-3*tet[2]^2,0, 2*tet[2],
                        -6*tet[1]*tet[2]), nrow=3,ncol=2)
  return(jacobian)
}
# Now we want to estimate the two parameters using the GMM.
gmm(g, x, c(0, 0), grad = Dg)
@

\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you please post your .lyx file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`is` is a function in the **methods** package, so you have to

```
library(methods)
```

The **methods** package is not loaded by default if the R script is executed from `Rscript`, per documentation of [`?Rscript`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/Rscript.html). That is how LyX calls R to load **knitr** and compiles the document.

Comment: Why would this be different in LyX as opposed to outside of LyX?

Comment: @scottkosty This fact just keeps on surprising people: http://stackoverflow.com/q/19680462/559676

Comment: @Yihui ah that is indeed interesting. Thanks for the link.